# nodejs/loopback: defining relationships doesn't seem to be reflected on database?

Tags: node.js, relationship, loopbackjs

I am creating an API with strongloop loopback.

I have defined my models, and basically all is good there.
But I have a problem understanding how loopback deals with relationships.

Not all of my relationships I defined seem to really be reflected in the database and the interface.

For example, I have a model `song`, it

- `hasAndBelongsToMany albums`
- `hasAndBelongsToMany playlists`
- `hasAndBelongsToMany userplaylists`
- `belongsTo artist`

Here is `/common/models/song.json`

```
{
  "name": "song",
  "plural": "song",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
   //some more properties of song
  }, 
  "validations": [], 
  "relations": {
    "albums": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "album",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },  
    "artist": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "artist",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },  
    "playlists": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "playlist",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },  
    "userplaylists": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "userplaylist",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }   
  },  
  "acls": [], 
  "methods": []
}
```

But when I look at the postgresql table generated, I see:

```
 title        | character varying(1024) | not null
 id           | integer                 | not null default nextval('song_id_seq'::regclass)
 #some other properties of song
 artistid     | integer                 |
```

Accordingly, the interface in loopbacks explorer at localhost:3000/explorer says:

```
post /song 
Response Class

    Model
    Model Schema

{
  "title": "",
  //some other properties of song
  "id": 0,
  "artistId": 0
}
```

The question: Shouldn't there also be a songs, a playlists and a userplaylists variable??? Or have I been working too much in the NoSql world and now I forgot how to handle relationships?

BTW. I have a migrate script which I executed when adding the relationships to the models:

```
var path = require('path');
var app = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../server'));

var dataSource = app.dataSources.cantoalegre_ps_DS;

dataSource.automigrate(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error migrating models: " + err);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Successfully migrated models");
  }
  process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

usually related data has the foreign key:

customer,
order belongs to customer so order has a column that contains the customer id.

Take care that at every change models have to be synchronized to the db by an autoupdate script.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
var ds = app.dataSources.pg;
ds.isActual('mymodel', function(err, actual) {
    if (!actual) {
        ds.autoupdate('mymodel', function(err, result) {
            console.log("AUTOUPDATE mymodel",err,result);
        });
    }
});
};
```